# Error calculating the area of a triangle?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that reads the base and height of a triangle of a triangle and then reports the area. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// a simple triangle class with a base and a height

class Triangle {

public:    
    double setbase(double x) { //was void but changed it to double
        base = x;
    }    
    double setheight(double y) {
        height = y;
    }
    double getbase() {
        return base;
    }
    double getheight() {
        return height;
    }

private:
    double base, height;
};    


double area(double, double);    

int main() {    

    Triangle isoscoles1;
    isoscoles1.setbase;
    isoscoles1.setheight;


    cin >> isoscoles1.setheight;
    cin >> isoscoles1.setbase;
    double x = isoscoles1.getbase;
    double y = isoscoles1.getheight;

    cout << "Triangle Area=" << area(x,y) << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
}


double area(double x, double y) {
    double a;
    a = (x*y) / 2;    

    return a;
}
```

This is the error it gives me:-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'Triangle::setbase': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member Project1    c:\users\ku\desktop\test\project1\main.cpp  50  
Error   C3867   'Triangle::setheight': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   Project1    c:\users\ku\desktop\test\project1\main.cpp  51  
Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    Project1    c:\users\ku\desktop\test\project1\main.cpp  54  
Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    Project1    c:\users\ku\desktop\test\project1\main.cpp  55  
Error   C3867   'Triangle::getbase': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member Project1    c:\users\ku\desktop\test\project1\main.cpp  56  
Error   C3867   'Triangle::getheight': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   Project1    c:\users\ku\desktop\test\project1\main.cpp  57
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider learning from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), rather than trying to code randomly.

Comment: Not very useful. but thanks for visiting

Comment: Why isn't it useful? The mistakes that you made, so trivial, that syntax regarding those, should be covered in the first chapters of any good book. By suggesting reading one, I could prevent you from making more of the similar problems in the future.

Comment: Which book would you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in these lines:

```
cin >> isoscoles1.setheight;
cin >> isoscoles1.setbase;
```

Remember that `setheight` and `setbase` are member functions, not actual variables. This would be like writing something like this:

```
void doSomething(double arg) {
    ...
}

cin >> doSomething; // Error - can't read into a function!
```

In the above case, you'd really do something like this:

```
double value;
cin >> value;
doSomething(value);
```

This separates out reading the value from calling the function.

Based on that, see if you can think about how you'd use an analogous solution to solve your own problem.

---

There's another issue here, as was pointed out in the comments. Take a look at these lines:

```
isoscoles1.setbase;
isoscoles1.setheight;
```

Think back to our `doSomething` function. Would you normally have a line of code like this?

```
doSomething;
```

You can safely delete those two lines; they don't actually do anything and they're causing some of the errors you're seeing.

Comment: The error is in the missing parenthesis in _attempted_ function `getbase`/`getheight` calls, as well.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified a few things. The code below now works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly.

`class Triangle {`
`public:
    void setbase(double x) { //was void but changed it to double
        base = x;
    }`

```
void setheight(double y) {
    height = y;
}
double getbase() {
    return base;
}
double getheight() {
    return height;
}
```

`private:
    double base;
    double height;
};`

`double area(double, double);`

`int main() {`

```
Triangle isoscoles1;
double x;
double y;
cin >> x >> y;

isoscoles1.setheight(y);
isoscoles1.setbase(x);
double b = isoscoles1.getbase();
double h = isoscoles1.getheight();

cout << "Triangle Area=" << area(x,y) << endl;
system("pause>nul");
return 0;
```

}

`double area(double x, double y) {
    double a;
    a = (x*y) / 2;`

```
    return a;
```

}